# Continuously rotate a graphic at a rate that matches compass rotation data

Tags: swift, uiview, rotation, compass

I'm building an iOS application that needs to smoothly rotate an image based on incoming compass heading data (actually, GPS ground track data arriving at 10 Hz from an aviation GPS system). I can easily animate rotation to the new desired angle with the correct duration (0.1 seconds) but the effect is still rough - you can tell that it's actually a series of discrete animations rather than one fluid motion. Here's the current very simple animation code:

```
    // rotate the compass ring
    if let cv = self.compassView {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
            cv.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(newAngle))
        })
    }
```

Does anyone have a good working algorithm for fluidly spinning things like this? Some clever means of creating a single animation (perhaps one that assumes a full 360) the speed of which is then modified as the rate of rotation changes? Apple's own compass app appears to do something similar.

Comment: Perhaps you can rotate the view some fixed percentage closer to the target angle on each frame?

Comment: I guess that's an option, but it would take me from transforming a simple object (a UIImageView) to handling all the internal state to draw on a frame-by-frame basis. As a lazy programmer, I would prefer to avoid that if possible.

Comment: You can probably use one of the spring animation options described here: https://medium.com/@flyosity/your-spring-animations-are-bad-and-it-s-probably-apple-s-fault-784932e51733  I think a critically damped or overdamped spring would give you what you're looking for, although I'm not certain changing the target position dynamically will work.